# Microsoft Dynamics AX MPos -Screen Layout

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, point-of-sale, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

On Screen Layout Designer.

When i Right Click on Main Screen design(Receipt panel) , it is showing customize option, there are some columns i can select for my MPos screen.

Is it possible to add my own columns or more specifically where it is getting these columns?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of what you are doing?

Comment: Image uploaded  on "http://s8.postimg.org/edd3atit1/2015_08_12_20_38_40.png"

Answer (score 0):

From [Online Store [AX 2012]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj937972.aspx), the Extends parts, see:

- [Walkthrough: Adding a table for customer preferences to the AX 2012 database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720785.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Extending the CRT to add customer preference data for Retail clients](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720790.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Extending retail data distribution infrastructure for customer preferences](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720788.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Adding customer preferences to the Retail online sample store](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720786.aspx)

If I read correctly, you have to modify the `CommerceRuntimeScripts.sql` to include the new fields.